# Resource Under Project A migrate to Project B in same organisation in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops

Is it possible to migrate the resources in Project A to Project B in same organisation in GCP ? If Yes, how can we do that ?

Comment: What are the GCP resources that you are trying to migrate from Project A to B?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the answer is no. You must recreate services to move them between projects.

There are many dependencies that most services have that are problematic to modify once created. Examples are VPC networking, service accounts, IAM permissions, etc. Some are very difficult to change via an automated tool as the changes might break internal applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to export your resource to terraform and to recreate them in the other project. However, nothing magic for the data...

There is a preview to generate a terraform. Never tried but it worths to have a look at it
https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform/resource-management/export

Comment: That will export the configuration of Google Cloud resources so that they can be recreated fresh (brand new). However, that will not migrate user data or application configuration details such as the OS, installed applications, etc.

Comment: Totally agree. Nothing magic for the data.

Comment: Your link is very useful when you want to start implementing Terraform for an existing environment. Saves a lot of time getting the Google Cloud resources into HCL.